# iOS UITableView Equivalent for WPF?

Tags: wpf

I'm recreating an iOS app in WPF that displays a popup window when a button is pressed that shows a `UITableView`. I need this functionality in my WPF application is there anything I can use that is similar to the iOS `UITableView`? I need to be able to select items in the table view which should then go to another `TableView` like in the image below:

[image: iOS TableView with Disclosure Indicators]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing will probably be the `ListBox`. If you want the little arrows on the right side of each item, you'll need to manually add an arrow image in the `ListBox.ItemTemplate`. Also, you'll need to manually code the navigation to go to another `ListBox`. I recommend reading articles on MVVM, if you're not familiar with this pattern already.

Having said this, if you're creating a desktop application, you may want to think about whether the same UX patterns apply to both your mobile and desktop app. Of course, I don't know what your app is, but I've created both mobile and desktop applications, and usually the interactions need to be modified because the user will have different expectations depending on the platform.